# Can a hacker access your email address and then choose to do nothing?

Tags: email

I have done a bit of research on what hackers look for in an email address, and it looks like any information is valuable to them, but a friend that knows about the subject has told me that it was possible that a hacker decides to do nothing to your account if you're "broke or a child".

I was confused, because I think even in that case, it would be possible (and useful) for them to send emails to the victim's contacts on their behalf or log them out and ask for ransom or something like that.

So, is it really possible that a hacker just gives up on your address, and if so, how likely is that?

Comment: This may sound a little funny, but can you be more specific about who/what you're worried about? There are several categories of "hacker", and they behave very differently. For example, are you worried that your company's competitors accessed your email? Are you worried about "script kiddies"? A competitor may just gather data silently or wait before taking action; a script kiddie would often be more opportunistic and do as much as they can immediately. Can you provide more detail on which type of hacker your worried about?

Comment: @FireQuacker I'm just a student so not the company thing lol. I'm worried about the kind of hackers that hack big databases using a security breach. I did research and it looks like any information is valuable to them : name, phone number... So they probably wouldn't leave the account alone, right ?

Comment: Hey, just a quick note: closing posts on Stack Exchange works a little differently from forums. Adding `(ANSWERED)` to the title is discouraged here. If you decide one of the answers is the correct answer, you can click the little check mark on the left side. But you don't really need to worry about closing it in the sense that forums traditionally close answered threads.

Comment: @Yanna, if you have gotten an answer that you think solves your problem you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only assume such things about hackers if they really were these guys from [Google image search on `hacker`](https://www.google.com/search?q=hacker&tbm=isch): working in their hoodies (hood on 24/7), always having dim blue lights and binary wallpapers – and leather gloves in their hands, as those are totally practical with keyboards.

In reality, there are many kind of hackers and cyber criminals with **different goals and motivations**. If an email account (or anything else compromised) is not useful for their interests, they *might* leave it alone.

- If it's purely for money, a target without money might not be profitable enough. If you have many potential victims, you'd go after the big fishes first, unless you can easily automate the attack.
- Spoofing email is ridiculously easy; compromising an email account just for sending email from it might not be efficient enough for the effort.
- If the motivation is something ethical, *hacktivism*, a compromised account might just be out of interest, or there might be moral barriers for doing something malicious, because he's for a good cause.

Although a hacker can be, do and choose not to do almost anything, this **can't be used for any risk assesment**, as you can't assume what you might be against. Just like assuming you *could* survive a high speed car crash you can't conclude speeding is safe.

Answer (score 2):

> So, is it really possible that a hacker just gives up on your address ....

Attacking something is a business. There are costs involved in doing the business and profit which can be made. Nothing is totally without costs, not even misusing a compromised account. If the profit of misusing a specific account is low or nonexistent it might simply not worth doing it - or at least an attacker might concentrate on the more worthwhile accounts before dealing with the low-profit accounts.

> ... , and if so, how likely is that ?

That's impossible to say in general. And it might change. Low-profit accounts might get profitable if new business opportunities emerge.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [Have I Been Pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/), they keep a pretty up-to-date database of breaches. You can input your email and see if it was involved in any breaches.

To more directly answer your question - Sure, it's possible they just leave your email alone if it isn't correlated to anything with value such as information, services, etc. They could attempt to send messages to your contacts, but most of your contacts would likely notice that the message content isn't normally something you would send them and would likely inform you.

In terms of locking you out of your account for ransom, the likelihood of them doing this for an account that doesn't have any value is virtually non-existent. Especially considering how simple it is to recover an email account these days. You don't really hear/read about access to emails being involved in ransom.

If you're genuinely worried that your account is compromised - make sure you change all of your passwords and consider setting up 2-factor authentication.

Comment: I used to trust Have I Been Pwned too but then I found out about some big leaks on Instagram that affected millions of users but couldn't find anything on the [Pwned Websites list](https://haveibeenpwned.com/PwnedWebsites) about it so... I wouldn't be so sure about that...

Answer (score -2):

Probably not because even if can access your email and discovers no helpful things, the attacker can do many things, such as sending emails, getting your phone number, personal data, etc. to blackmail you. Even if the email account doesn't have any link access to other valuable accounts.

In case of mass account hacks, they usually use/sell your emails linked with services or simply for spamming/phishing.

Comment: Not my down vote, but anyway. I agree that you answered the question. I think your answer is incorrect, because you are basically saying that a hacker would never leave a compromised account alone. The other answers gives good examples of when a hacker might choose to do just that.